# AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, delete-file, access-denied

com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;

I want to delete the file from the s3 bucket using sprint boot api. I think the api is working fine. I must be making some mistake, not sure. I am trying to do this action as a root user.

This is my code to delete the file from S3. Key is the name of the file.
public void deleteImage(String key) {

```
try {
    getS3Object.deleteObject(bucketName, key);
} catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
    throw new CommonException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Failed to delete file from     S3");
   }
}
```

I have set the S3 bucket policy as
"Action": [
"s3:PutObject",
"s3:GetObject",
"s3:DeleteObject"
],

I tried by enabling ACL and also bucket versioning. Please help me solve this.

Comment: It is unusual to use a Bucket Policy to grant `DeleteObject` permission. Usually, such permissions are granted to an IAM User or IAM Role. Can you show us the complete Bucket Policy?

Comment: Note that you are using the Java V1 version which is offiically on the path to deprecation. AWS recommends that you update to Java v2 which works fine within a Spring Boot app. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-end-of-support-for-aws-sdk-for-java-v1-x-on-december-31-2025/